# How do I resolve "You have already activated test-unit" errors in my Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

As Heroku doesn’t seem to support MySQL, I’m trying to build their project to convert my MySql db to PostgreSQL, per https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-mysql.  However, I’m getting this error:

```
localhost:mysql2postgres davea$ mysqltopostgres
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7@global/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:34:in `block in setup': You have already activated test-unit 2.1.7.0, but your Gemfile requires test-unit 3.1.7. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7@global/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7@global/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:92:in `setup'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7@global/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7@global/gems/mysqltopostgres-0.3.0/bin/mysqltopostgres:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/bin/mysqltopostgres:23:in `load'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/bin/mysqltopostgres:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I have no idea what this means and running the same command with `bundle exec` prepended doesn’t solve the problem.